# How to access a variable in a PHP object structure

Tags: php, mongodb

I want to parse this MongoDB error message. I can't manage to access the variables in the object. I assume I overlook something trivial, but I can't figure it out.

The var_dump `var_dump($error);`

```
object(MongoDB\Driver\WriteError)#11 (4) {
        ["message"]=>
        string(362) "E11000 duplicate key error collection: database.collection index: c_address collation: { locale: "nl", caseLevel: false, caseFirst: "off", strength: 1, numericOrdering: false, alternate: "non-ignorable", maxVariable: "punct", normalization: false, backwards: false, version: "57.1" } dup key: { address: "0x", city: "0x" }"
        ["code"]=>
        int(11000)
        ["index"]=>
        int(0)
        ["info"]=>
        NULL
      }
```

I try to access message and print it out with `echo`.

`echo $error->message;`

Throws: *Warning: Undefined property: MongoDB\Driver\WriteError::$message*

`echo $error["message"];`

Throws: *Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type MongoDB\Driver\WriteError as array*

Comment: Your first instinct when dealing with an object should be to look for the [class documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-writeerror.php).

Comment: Generally, lots of these objects won't expose their properties as public, so you should assume a getter exists - you just need to find the documentation to see what it's called.

Comment: Thanks @El_Vanja. Indeed class documentation mentions getMessage() and that works. Is there a way to see from the var_dump that those variables are not public?

Comment: Well, normally, it should be visible (see [fiddle](https://3v4l.org/BemYJ)). They probably intentionally obscured this information, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216334/hide-specific-class-fields-from-print-r-or-var-dump) for details.

Comment: I use PHP8 and run it in the terminal in VS Code on MacOs. Maybe a php config setting.

Comment: I found how it can be altered and edited my comment.

Answer (score 1):

The class documentation suggestion from El_Vanja did the trick.
MongoDB\Driver\WriteError has a method `[getMessage][1]`.

My first assumption is to check with var_dump what I get back and it's impossible to see if those variables are protected/private or not (and if they have a function).

I did some more research, converting an object to json and echo that, at least shows which variables are public (in this case none).

`echo json_encode($error);`
Gives: `{}`.

Comment: If you are just looking for some quick ways to debug things, this method totally works. If you are looking to dive deeper and/or make something more utilitarian you'd want to look into reflection, or a function such as `get_object_vars`

Comment: Alternatively, I would suggest a dumping library (I use Kint myself) which has advanced capabilities and is able to shell out a ton of information about the object (including all properties and available methods). Basically, other people have already devised more complex solutions that dive deeper, as Chris suggested. Might as well use that.